# PM2 errors for node app

Tags: node.js, express, pm2

I'm trying to PM2 start my node app and i get the following errors in the index-error log for PM2

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::80
at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:837:11)
at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:860:20)
at Server._listen2 (net.js:1231:14)
at listen (net.js:1267:10)
at Server.listen (net.js:1363:5)
at Function.app.listen (/var/www/Feed-App/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:556:24)
at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/Feed-App/index.js:12:5)
at Module._compile (module.js:434:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
```

Any idea what this means? I'm using express.js